# Ubuntu - alternative to Acronis True Image

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I'm considering switching from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.04. On Windows, I'm using Acronis True Image 2012 for Backup, which has these three key features for me:

- **Backup system partition** and recover it via bootable CD (protects me from OS damage, I could be back and running with all my programs and settings in just one hour)
- Backup selected folders using **differential/incremental backup** (I back up every week and use 1 full backup + 7 chains. Chain backup usually takes just 10-15 mins and full backup every 2 months I could survive)
- Possibility to **mount any backed-up version as read-only device**, so I can naturally and transparently access and manipulate all my files in the backup.

AES 256 Encryption would be also fine, but this could be solved another way - to store an entire backup of the encrypted partition.

I have tried DejaDup which is preinstalled on Ubuntu, but I was not able to access backed up files another way than completely restore the backup, which is insufficient.

What do you recommend me?

Comment: I'm using acronis since 2009 to restore partitions both windows and linux too because there's a bootable cd that manage ext2-4 partitions and even the same acronis disc runs in a linux environment not as norton back up that is designed to work only in windows systems!

Comment: This type of question is a better fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nice [comparison of some commonly used backup utilities](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) on community wiki.
I'd recommend [Bacula](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bacula).

Answer (score 1):

For the /home folders (and any other user data folders), I suggest going with something simple like rsnapshot, rdiff-backup or rsync w/ hard-links.  All of them store at least one (or all) backup revisions as **regular files in the file system**.  All of them can work with remote targets over the network or local folders as the backup target.  They're all command-line tools, which makes for easy scripting and execution via the cron command.  Combine that with LVM snapshots and you can easily mount a read-only copy of the backup target file system, without worrying that you'll damage your backup directory.

Note: I strongly believe that all file systems should be inside of LVM logical volumes where possible.  The only exceptions with GRUB 0.9x is /boot and / (root) because it doesn't know how to read those.  But /home, /srv, /yourlocaldata, and other file systems can easily be placed into LVs.

For example, with rdiff-backup:

- The most recent version of any file is stored as a plain file in the target directory.  So restoring or viewing the most recently backed up file is very easy.
- Previous versions of a file are stored as a compressed diff, which makes it very space-efficient.
- You can choose any backup retention period you want, depending on what time period you pass to "--remove-older-than" in a second run of rdiff-backup.
- rdiff-backup directories are very friendly for rsync over the WAN to a remote site.  Or for rsync'ing to an external USB drive.

For bare-metal restore of system configuration -- I don't have a better recommendation then those linked.  But as long as you make sure to put your own data on separate file systems, it gets a lot easier to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind - CloneZilla [link](http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is definitely not what I'm looking for, because of these limitations: 1) Differential/incremental backup is not implemented yet. 2) Online imaging/cloning is not implemented yet. The partition to be imaged or cloned has to be unmounted.